# Erro ao Executar app no Celular

Tags: android

Estou com problemas pois estou criando 1 App e executo numa boa no emulador. E quando executo no **celular** da esse erro abaixo...

**Obs: no cel ele abre e fecha.**

**Obs2: no emulador roda perfeitamente.**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dutra_pc.navigation_teste, PID: 21972
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4981212 byte allocation with 3804820 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2477)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2384)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
at com.example.dutra_pc.navigation_teste.ButaoAdapter.getView(ButaoAdapter.java:35)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1196)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15689)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5040)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2116)
at android.
```

No emulador >>>[image: Emulador utilizado android studio]

```
package com.example.dutra_pc.navigation_teste;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_ini, new Content_Ini())
                    .commit();

        }

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        final ArrayList<Butao>butaos = adicionar();
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ButaoAdapter(this,butaos);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Butao butao = (Butao) adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,butao.getNome(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(position ==0){
                    //LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
                    /*if(savedInstanceState == null){
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.cosProg, new Frag_Ini())
                                .commit();
                                Comando para iniciar fragments
                    }*/

                    //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
                    //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_ini, new Comunicacao()).commit();
                    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                }else if (position ==1 ){
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_ini, new Programacao()).commit();
                    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    private ArrayList<Butao>adicionar(){
        ArrayList<Butao>butaos = new ArrayList<>();
        Butao a = new Butao("Comunicação", R.drawable.comunicacao);
        butaos.add(a);
        Butao b = new Butao("Programação", R.drawable.programacao);
        butaos.add(b);
        Butao c = new Butao("Eventos", R.drawable.eventos);
        butaos.add(c);
        Butao d = new Butao("Caravanas", R.drawable.caravanas);
        butaos.add(d);
        Butao e = new Butao("Experiência de fé", R.drawable.experiencia);
        butaos.add(e);
        Butao f = new Butao("Cultos", R.drawable.cultos);
        butaos.add(f);
        Butao g = new Butao("Aniversários", R.drawable.aniversarios);
        butaos.add(g);
        Butao h = new Butao("Secretaria", R.drawable.secretaria);
        butaos.add(h);
        Butao i = new Butao("Formação Jovem", R.drawable.formacao_jovens);
        butaos.add(i);
        Butao j = new Butao("Contato", R.drawable.contato);
        butaos.add(j);
        Butao k = new Butao("Compartilhar", R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
        butaos.add(k);

        return butaos;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        //ArrayList<Butao>butaos = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Butao>butaos = adicionar();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ButaoAdapter(this,butaos);



        int id = item.getGroupId();

        if (id == R.id.textView1) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: O aplicativo precisa `4981212` de memória, mas só tem `3804820` de espaço disponível.

Comment: @wmsouza celular tem 8Gb de  memória se serve de ajuda essa informação para algo...

Comment: Seria interessante compartilhar conosco o código! Quando falo de memória, falo da biblioteca **OOM** que tentou alocar mais memória do que disponível naquele momento. Coloque em seu arquivo **manifest** na tag `application` isso: `android:hardwareAccelerated="false", android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: @wmsouza q parte do código ?

Comment: Muito Obrigado! tu é o Cara! hahaha funcionou! tem como explicar o q foi feito ? @wmsouza ?

Comment: Cara, tem alguma imagem pesada no seu aplicativo (nas telas dele)? Porque se sim, geralmente é isto... Imagens de 2MB, 1.5MB geralmente causam esse tipo de problema.

Comment: @itscorey nenhuma imagem chega a isso tudo n elas estão em KB

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro é muito comum no Android, quando um objeto não pode ser alocado devido à falta de espaço de memória e também, o coletor de lixo não pode libertar espaço. Para resolver, deve-se adicionar as propriedades abaixo no arquivo **manifest**.

```
<application
    ...
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

- [**hardwareAccelerated**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

  Habilita ou desabilita a aceleração do hardware, valor padrão é `true`
- [**largeHeap**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)

  Habilita ou desabilita aumento fixo na memória disponível. Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) não é garantido o aumento.