# Por que sempre na sexta ImageView que coloco o App trava

Tags: android, imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lampiaoId"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="164dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/lampiao_aceso"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/quartoEscuroId"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/lampiaorecortado" />
```

São 6 códigos como o acima, mas sempre que coloco a sexta imagem o app não roda.

Todas as imagens t~em isso:
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/quartoEscuroId"

Liguei todas ao top da imagem de fundo.

Comment: Aparece algum erro no LogCat?

Comment: Acabei de ver no SatckOverflow inglês:  android:largeHeap="true"  Coloquei isso no Manifest e agora foi. Acho que minhas imagens estão grandes, vou diminuir o tamanho. è algo com uso de memória.

Comment: [Erro ao Executar app no Celular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267400).